# Cut/Copy/Paste in Image Editor?

Tags: uv-image-editor

It's a pretty simple question. I was wondering if it was able to cut/copy and paste images in Image Editor in Blender? Almost like box select in 3D view, maybe?

Comment: As stated by pycoder Blender's image editor is more of a node based procedural worflow kind of editor, not a photo editor with manual selection tools like say GIMP or Photoshop. There is no direct user action with the canvas nor interactive tools.

Comment: Now you can, with my free addon https://github.com/Yeetus3141/ImagePaste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't as of yet. The image editor is pretty basic at the moment. You could use cloning if you'd like, but that is much more involved (and a waste of time if you just need to copy/paste). Just use an external image editing application such as gimp or photoshop.